# what is an appropriate shape name as my routine does not say?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

i have the following routine that i found on the net here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=77662

this routine isn't working cause i dont know that shape name. can anyone tell me what the shape name is for a rectangular box?

```
Function SetShapeText(s As String, sShpName As String) 
s = "some text"
Dim i As Integer 

ActiveSheet.Shapes(sShpName).Select 

With Selection 
    .Text = "" 
    For i = 0 To Int(Len(s) / 255) 
        .Characters(.Characters.Count + 1).Text = Mid(s, 255 * i + 1, 255) 
    Next 
End With 
End Function
```

it errors out on this line: ActiveSheet.Shapes(sShpName).Select

Comment: You need to look at the shape. Or print the shape names. Or take a guess with `Rectangle 1` Also that's a function so you need to pass the shape's name as a string into the function.

Comment: see new code above, rectangle 1 doesn't work. do i have it formatted correctly?

Comment: No, you do not. The `sShpName` is the variable the function uses, you can't change it. You need to call the function with your shape name as the string. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the first one to get the names. The second one here shows you how to call the function you have there.

```
Sub myshapes()
Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print shp.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub sendit()
Dim shpnm As String
shpnm = "Rectangle 1"
Dim mystring As String
mystring = "blah blah"
Dim x As Variant
x = SetShapeText(mystring, shpnm)

End Sub
```

See, you have a function there that requires two inputs: s, sShpName

To use a function you need to call it pass your arguments into it like above. No reason to change anything within the function.

Comment: i tried what you coded, fails on line below (still) ActiveSheet.Shapes(sShpName).Select, i kept the function and added your two subs.

Comment: You aren't using the function correctly. What is your `s`? What is your shape name? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i added s = "some text" in the function above. what i am trying to accomplish is to query the user for a text string and then put it into a rectangle text box (might need more than 255 characters, which is why i am using a text box and not a comment) in the current cell

Comment: Well, I've answered your initial question. It seems you're pretty lost here, maybe you should google around and learn how to do it, rather than relying on what you find.

Comment: yup, i am definitely lost. so i query the user for a text string, i know how to do that. but calling the textbox routine, i dont know how to do. i just want a text string to appear in a rectangle box in the current cell.